# Using <form:select> and <form:option> with converter but conversion does not happens, why?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have this form for creating an `Enrichment`:

```
<form:form method="post" action="..." modelAttribute="enrichment">
    ...
    <form:select path="tag"> 
        <form:options items="${tagList}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="label" />
    </form:select>
    ...
```

The `Enrichment` class has a `Tag` attribute. So when th user has selected a tag in the Tag list, tag.id (wich is a String) is sent throught the form. I don't think I could directly send a tag object am I wright? So I wrote a Converter to convert a String to a Tag, according to http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert-Converter-API. So I did this :

```
public class IdToTagConverter implements Converter<String, Tag> {

    @Autowired
    TagService tagService;

    public Tag convert(String id) {     
        return tagService.findTagById(Integer.parseInt(id));
    }
}
```

And I created the bean :

```
<bean id="conversionService"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <list>
            <bean class="exemple.IdToTagConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And I thought it would do the convertion automatically. But the error message is still here :

> [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to
>   required type 'exemple.Tag' for property 'tag'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type
>   [java.lang.String] to required type [exemple.Tag] for property 'tag':
>   no matching editors or conversion strategy found]

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution here : 
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?84003-Converters-no-matching-editors-or-conversion-strategy-found

I just replaced

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

by

```
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService" />
```

and it worked. Why? Spring MVC Voodoo.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Spring is not aware of your converter, or Conversion Service. Follow this part of the documentation to register your custom converter - > http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#format-configuring-FormattingConversionService